# How to create Rectangle Shape with inside round corners

Tags: android

[image]

I want to create Drawable like the White Shape shown in above Image.

I tries it using following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<corners android:radius="40dp" />

<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />

<size
    android:height="150dp"
    android:width="150dp" /></shape>
```

But I'm getting Output like this..

[image]

I also tried `layer-list` with multiple Shapes but not able to get the desired output..

Also my `ImageView`'s height and width are calculated in code..so I also don't want to pass size in drawable. Is it possible??

Comment: You want a **white** rectangle with a **smaller, cornered black** rectangle inside it.

Comment: you have 2 possible solutions: 1) a nine-patch-drawable, 2) a ShapeDrawable with a custom Shape class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw the shape with the following xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#fff" ></solid>

            <size
                android:width="100dp"
                android:height="100dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="#000" ></solid>
            <size
                android:width="90dp"
                android:height="90dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

We draw two items upon each other. A white square on first layer and put another black square with 10dp radius and 5dp padding inside white square.

Also you can control width and height of the imageView which your drawable assigned, it scales accordingly.

[image: small version]

[image: large version 200dp]